# Combining Sin Curves on Google Line Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have data for sin curves of differing magnitudes over time and I would like to combine all the curves into a single curve on a chart.

Is it possible to do this with the Google Chart API or can alternative approaches be recommended?

Comment: http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=t:-1|15,45&chs=250x150&chco=FF0000,000000&chfd=0,x,0,9.5,0.1,sin(x)*50%2B50&chxt=x,y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's Chart API isn't a graphic calculator. It displays pre-calculated data, not equations. So if you have the results pre-calculated for a series of x-values, then yes, the Chart API can plot it.
(If the number of points is < ~5k, a Google Spreadsheet is probably your fastest route to try it out.)

If you don't have the results already calculated - if you just have the equations - then your problem's more of a maths question than a Chart API question. (But again, a spreadsheet might be a fast way to get going.)

Comment: Thanks Kris, that answers my question. I will calculate the points elsewhere and then plot the resulting curve using Google Chart.